# issues with jquery validate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using a jquery validation Plugin, I had the following code for validation which is troubling, it is just a specification how i want the error should display on the screen

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('form.CWvalidate').each(function() {
        var alertID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        jQuery(this).prepend('<div class="CWalertBox alertText validationAlert" style="display:none;"></div><div class="CWclear"></div>');
    });
    jQuery('form.CWvalidate select').change(function() {
        jQuery(this).blur();
    });
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        focusInvalid: true,
        onkeyup: false,
        onblur: true,
        errorClass: "warning",
        errorElement: "span",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            jQuery(element).siblings('label').addClass('warning');
        },
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            if (this.numberOfInvalids() > 0) {
                var formID = jQuery(this.currentForm).attr('id');
                if (formID == 'CWformCustomer') {
                    var validationMessage = 'Complete all required information';
                } else if (formID == 'CWformLogin') {
                    var validationMessage = '';
                } else if (formID == 'CWformOrderSubmit') {
                    var validationMessage = 'Complete all required information';
                } else if (formID == 'CWformAddToCartWindow') {
                    var validationMessage = 'Select at least one item';
                } else if (formID == 'CWformAddToCart') {
                    var validationMessage = 'Choose from below options before adding to cart';
                } else {
                    var validationMessage = 'Complete your selection';
                };
                if (!(validationMessage == '')) {
                    jQuery(this.currentForm).find('.errormsg').show().html(validationMessage);
                };
                this.defaultShowErrors();
            } else {
                jQuery(this.currentForm).children('div.validationAlert').empty().hide();
                jQuery(this.currentForm).children('span.warning').remove();
                jQuery(this.currentForm).children('.warning').removeClass('warning');
            }
        }
    });
    jQuery('form.CWvalidate').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).validate();
    });
});
```

but whenever I ma using this classwhich is `CWvalidate`, the form validates but the submithandler of the form does not which i use it like below code:

```
$("#dataModification").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
    var datastring = $(form).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: 'xyz.cfm',
        data: datastring,
        success: function(data) {
            var obj = $.trim(data);

            if (obj == 'success'){
                parent.$.fancybox.close();
            }else{
                alert(obj);
            }
          }
       });
    }
});
```

What is wrong I am stuck and do not know what is going on...

Comment: Any errors in the console?  Are you able to hit any breakpoints?

Comment: nothing, nothing in console and it basically half works, i mean validation works but when it goes to submit handler, it just refreshes the whole page

Comment: Please show the relevant rendered HTML markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be calling `.validate()` twice on the same form...

Here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    ....
    jQuery('form.CWvalidate').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).validate();
    });
});
```

And here:

```
$("#dataModification").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) { 
    ...
```

Only the first instance is used and any subsequent instances are ignored, which explains why your `submitHandler` is not working and the form simply refreshes.  It also explains why it only fails when using your `CWvalidate` class.

To fix it, you'll have to figure out how to call `.validate()` **one** time per each form.

One possible workaround would be to put your ajax URL within the `action` attribute of the `form` tag and then retrieve this URL within `.ajax()` using `.attr('action')`.  Then your `submitHandler` can be generic enough to be included within `setDefaults()`.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    var datastring = $(form).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: $(form).attr('action'), ...
```

---

Also note:  There is no such option called `onblur` for this plugin.  It's `onfocusout` and you cannot set it to `true` without breaking the plugin.  [It can only be set to `false` or a function](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onfocusout).